# Disable SSLv3 on WSO2 WSAS 3.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-wsas

I am administering an instance of WSO2 WSAS 3.1. After searching for the documentation, I couldn't find anything related to how to change ssl/tls protocols.

Does anyone knows how can I disable the SSLv3 in this version of WSO2 WSAS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I had to change the SSL/TLS protocols in [wso2_home]/conf/transports.xml

FROM:

```
<transport name="https"  class="org.wso2.carbon.server.transports.http.HttpsTransport">
    <parameter name="port">9443</parameter>

    <parameter name="sslProtocol">TLS</parameter>
```

TO:

```
<transport name="https" class="org.wso2.carbon.server.transports.http.HttpsTransport">
    <parameter name="port">9443</parameter>

    <parameter name="sslProtocols">SSLv2Hello,TLSv1</parameter>
```

Then stop and start the service.